# How to prove that $f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+n\sin(x)}$ does not converge uniformly on $[0, \pi/2]$?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

If $f_n$ is a sequence of functions over $[0, \pi/2]$ given by

$$f_n(x) = \frac {nx} {1+n\sin(x)},$$

then how would I go about proving that $f_n$ does not converge uniformly to a function $f$ on $[0, \pi/2]$?

Comment: What is $f$? That seems the crucial question.

Comment: One way is to note the pointwise limit function isn't continuous. (You can show the result directly though.)

Comment: Point -wise convergent to which function ?

Comment: It seems like that converges to a function that is zero at zero and one everywhere else.  Since that's not continuous and $f_n$ is for all $n$, it cannot converge uniformly.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Not one everywhere else, but to $x/ \sin(x)$.

Comment: f is when $n \to \infty$

Comment: @DavidMitra Right.  Still not continuous at $0$ tho...

Comment: Right, but if you answer what $f$ is, actually, then you'll see why it doesn't converge uniformly. @Kittu

Comment: If $(f_n)$ is a sequence of continuous functions uniformly convergent to $f$, then $f$ is continuous. As your point-wise limit is not continuous, this proves that the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: For a direct proof, show $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}  |f_n(x)-f(x)|=1$, where $f$ is the pointwise limit. That the convergence is not uniform follows from the definition of uniform continuity. Nothing else is needed.  (Looking at the graphs of $f$ and $f_n$ is worthwhile.)

Comment: @Kittu can I ask where you got this problem from? Looking at your history my teacher gives out very similar problems. Is it from a book?

Comment: How can this question be duplicate of that. Both are different one uses $[0, \pi/2]$ while other is $[a, \pi/2]$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ f(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{nx}{1+n\sin(x)} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{x/\sin(x)}{\frac{1}{n\sin(x)}+1} = \frac{x}{\sin(x)} \quad (x \neq 0) $$

and $$ f(0) =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n(0)}{1+n\sin(0)} = 0 $$

but 
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0+} f(x)=1$$

so $f$ is not continuous at $0$. The $f_n$ are all continuous at $0$ and if the sequence converged uniformly to $f$ then $f$ would be continuous at $0$. Since $f$ is not continuous at $0$ we can conclude that the sequence does not converge uniformly.

Comment: Nice answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

When $x=0$ then $f(x)=0$.

When $x\not = 0$ then $f(x)=\frac{x}{\sin x}$.

So, $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{ for } x=0\\\frac{x}{\sin x} & \text{ for } x\in (0,\pi/2]\end{cases}$$As, $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$,  so $\{f_n(x)\}$ is NOT uniform convergent.

Comment: When $x\neq 0$ we have $f(x) = x/\sin(x)$, not $f(x)=1$. Though, I am not the down voter.

Comment: The error is still in line two.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729, in your second line you wrote "When $x\neq 0$ then $f(x)=1$." This still needs to be fixed.