# Showing Uniform convergence of $\frac{n x}{1 + n \sin(x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

I want to prove for all $a\in \left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$, $ \ f_n\to f$ uniformly on $\left[a,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$.
Also, how is this different from $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $\left(0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ ?

I made the crucial error of omitting that first line, when I asked this question before.

---

Let us define:
$$f_n(x) = \frac{n x}{1 + n \sin(x)}$$

Which has pointwise convergence to $f(x)$ if:

$$x = 0, \ f(x) = 0, \text{ and } x \in \left(0, \frac{\pi}{2}\,\right], \ f(x) = \frac{x}{\sin(x)}$$

---

Here is my attempt at the problem:

If $x \in \left(0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ then 
$$\left|\, f_n(x) - f(x) \right|  = 
\left| \frac{nx}{1 + n\sin(x)} - \frac{x}{\sin(x)}\right| 
\\
= \left|\frac{nx \sin(x) - x\, \big(1 + n \sin(x)\big)}{\big(1+ n \sin(x)\big)\sin(x)} \right|
\\
 = \frac{x}{\sin(x) + n \sin^2(x)} \leq \frac{1}{n},
$$
is this line correct?

So $\forall \epsilon > 0$, we may choose $N \geq \frac{1}{\epsilon}$ such that when $n \geq N \implies \left|\,f_n(x)-f(x)\right| \leq \epsilon \quad \forall x \in \left(0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$

---

I am not satisfied or confident in my answer, may anyone else suggest improvements?

Comment: Your bound is wrong, take $x=\pi/2$.

Comment: Thanks @CheeHan. Is the idea/approach correct, however? Finding some upper bound?

What about

$ \frac{x}{\sin(x) + n \sin^2(x)} \leq \frac{\pi}{n}$

Instead

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does $\frac{nx}{1+n \sin(x)}$ uniformly converge on $(0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1300277/does-fracnx1n-sinx-uniformly-converge-on-0-frac-pi2)

Comment: @elbarto):Why you ask same question again and again? If you have some question about your question then leave comment in your old question..and modified it..

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 Because you marked the prior one as a duplicate, despite my edit making it a completely different question - it lost all its' traction.

Please don't do it again, I have no idea why some people jump at the opportunity to mark a question as a duplicate, it is inconsiderate.

Note in this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299906/how-to-prove-that-f-nx-fracnx1n-sinx-does-not-converge-uniformly-to the OP included $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ for the domain, whereas my question is asking for convergence for all $a \in (0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ - a completely different question.

Comment: This seems almost character-for-character identical to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1300277/91818); I can't see much of an argument against closing as a duplicate.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones It is the same question, but the other question was wrongfully marked as a duplicate and thus became invalid.
In my experience, when a question is marked as a duplicate, people do not pay attention to it. If I was wrong to make another thread, then I apologise. 
As you can see, this question was answered correctly in under an hour, whilst that one received no attention in the 8 hours it's been up.

It is frustrating to see such a pedantic approach to marking duplicates and closing questions, and counter-intuitive to the nature of this site in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-uniform convergence on $(0,\pi/2]$ was addressed (partially) in another post. It follows from $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}|f_n(x) - f(x)|= 1$ for any sequence $(x_n)$ with $x_n \to 0$.

Convergence is uniform on $[a,\pi/2]$ for $0 < a  < \pi/2$.

Note that as $n \to \infty$ we have for all $x \in [a,\pi/2]$,

$$|f_n(x) - f(x)| = \frac{x}{\sin x + n \sin^2 x} \leqslant \frac{\pi}{2n \sin^2 a}\to 0.$$

Comment: Oh, this is because $\sin(x) \geq \sin(a)$ on $[a, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ - correct?

with this upperbound in mind, do I approach with the regular

$\forall \space \epsilon > 0 \space \text{choose an} \space N \geq \dots$ to complete the proof?

Comment: Yes -- we can find $N(\epsilon)$ independent of $x$ such that $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ when $n \geqslant N(\epsilon)$

Comment: You are welcome.  The question of UC on $[a,\pi/2]$ is different than that of $(0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: I think I still do not understand why this is, but will spend some time digesting it.

Comment: Well UC on $[a,\pi/2]$ follows because $|f_n(x) - f(x)|$ is bounded above by a sequence converging to zero that depends only on fixed $a$ -- the bound is uniform for all $x \in [a,\pi/2]$.  Is it the non-uniform convergence on $(0,\pi/2]$ that concerns you?

Comment: Yea, I mean it seems odd to me though, what is the fundamental difference between $x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ and $x \in a$ for $a \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$

Also just wanted to clarify, in your answer, you say: "convergence is uniform on $[a, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ for $0 < a < \frac{\pi}{2}$

Should this not be $a \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ ?

Comment: ... for any fixed $a$ between $0$ and $\pi/2$ excluding $0$.  So $a = \pi/2$ is acceptable as a trivial case since this reduces to pointwise convergence at $\pi/2$.

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Comment: If $a > 0$ then we have uniform convergence since we can't keep choosing smaller and smaller values of $x$ that keep the difference $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ greater than say $1/2$ regardless of how large $n$ is.